# Exactly what happens when nitrogen is converted into C14

Tags: organic-chemistry

When a cosmic ray ( neutron) strikes a nitrogen atom in the atmosphere, does the cosmic ray knock one of the nitrogen electrons out of its orbit and into one of the protons in the nitrogen nucleus? Does the cosmic ray just continue on its way through the atmosphere? Is the electron that got knocked out of orbit absorbed  into the proton making it become a neutron? And when radioactive decay occurs in the c14, does the neutron that used to be a proton spit out an electron that becomes part of that atom or does it go out into space?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon-14#Natural_production_in_the_atmosphere . Not really chemistry, IMO.

Comment: @Gert - Glenn Seaborg might beg to differ! But, yes, nuclear chemistry has been ceded in entirety to nuclear physics. Plus, I would add that the cross section for the 14N(n,p)14C reaction rises again above 100keV, so it is not purely thermal neutrons that take part.

Comment: Please bare with me as I know very little about chemistry and physics. So , when 14C is formed in the upper atmosphere, the random negative neutron that strikes the atom of nitrogen is then absorbed into one of the protons in the nucleus along with one of the atoms electrons, this resulting in an atom that has 6 electrons, 8 neutrons, and 6 protons ( one of the protons having absorbed an electron of the nitrogen atom and a free neutron from space) ?

Comment: Also, when the 14C nucleus erodes and turns back into 14N , does the proton that became a neutron emit an electron that then orbits that atom and also emit a neutron that then exits the atom and becomes a free negative neutron?

Comment: First, the reaction I wrote in my comment means you start with a 14N, a neutron goes in, a proton comes out, and you are left with 14C. For you most recent comment, try to write out that reaction and see what the result would be (hint - you appear to be trying to create nucleons from nothing).

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for taking the time to answer my questions. I am just curious as to what exactly happens to all the particles involved in this event . I have read dozens of articles online but am curious if the negative neutron from space that collides with the nitrogen atom becomes part of one of its protons along with one of the electrons and if both of those particles are then spit back out of the neutron they created when the nucleus erodes and becomes nitrogen again

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say is what happens to the electrons of 14N and Where do the electrons come from when 14N is recreated at beta decay. I understand that the proton becomes a neutron when a neutron is added and I understand that a neutron becomes a proton in Beta decay but where does the 7th electron come from in the newly formed atom and where does it go when nitrogen becomes carbon?

Comment: It's a nuclear reaction. The normal electrons around the original nucleus do not take part in it, except for very heavy elements where the inner electrons (1s) are very close to the nucleus. Neutrons are not negative, but neutral, and beta decay is when one gives off an electron and thereby turns into a proton.

Comment: So does an atom of 14C have 7 electrons or 6?

Comment: @Dale An atom is electrically neutral and has as many electrons as its core has protons.

Comment: So the newly formed 14C drops one existing electron from the atom’s Shell and does it spit out an up quark from one of its protons or does the impact from the electron from space cause the bosons that already exist in the quark to change the quark to a down quark (is the quark changed in the proton or is it replaced). In beta decay do the bosons just decide they want to change a down quark into an up quark so that the nucleus can be stable and when this is done do these bosons actually create a new quark? I am assuming that they must because an up quark has to come from somewhere .